# Почему выдает ошибку Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setOnClickListeneron a null object referenc

Tags: android, android-fragment, firebase

У меня в фрагменте есть GridLayout в нем выводиться фотографии пользователей из Firebase.Я хочу что бы при нажатии на любое из фото в GridLayout у меня с помощью интента переходило на новую активити в которой будет выводиться более детальная информация о пользователе.Вот мой фрагмент кода где я с помощью интента хочу перейти  новую активити, а мне выдает Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object referenc. Я не понимаю почему он мне говорит что он пустой. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
gridUserImage = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutUsers);
    gridUserImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsFragment.this.getActivity(), User_layout_fullscreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `RelativeLayoutUsers` - это что? Как минимум вью-элементы фрагмента нужно искать в его корневом контейнере, а не в активности. Делается это в `onViewCreated` либо в `onCreateView`. А вообще `GridLayout` не лучшее решение, если количество фотографий не строго постоянное, а тем более если их намного больше чем умещается в один экран. Возможно стоит обратить внимание на `RecyclerView` или `GridVew`. К тому же в вашем подходе сложно определить на кого именно нажали - вы ведь должны ещё передать эту информацию в активность детализации, чтобы там отобразить не кого попало, а того кого выбрали

Comment: RelativeLayoutUsers - это id шаблона как выглядит один из пунктов GridLayout.
Я хочу реализовать ленту которая выглядит как GridLayout.И в ней будет выводиться фотографии всех пользователей и при нажатии на фото будет открываться активити с более детальной информацией о пользователе(фото,логин, возраст, возможность поставить лайк и т.д).Такую вот задачу удобно реализовывать через GridLayout или это вообще абсолютно неправильный подход?